# Redirecting URL to different web app in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Posted this to serverfault, but then decided it was more of a stackoverflow deal.  I am running tomcat 6.0, and am having trouble configuring it to do what I want...

I have two web apps, call them X and Y, deployed as X.war and Y.war. Each has a servlet called blah.

So I can access them like so: http://server/X/blah http://server/Y/blah

What I want to do is pretend they are one web application Z, and be able to do this:

http://server/Z/X/blah --> as if I'd gone to http://server/X/blah

http://server/Z/Y/blah --> as if I'd gone to http://server/Y/blah

So I changed the (catalina_home)/conf/Catalina/localhost/X.xml as follows: < context override="true" path="/Z/X" reloadable="false" > .  Similar for Y.xml.

However that didn't work out; when going to http://server/Z/X/blah I get

> "The requested resource (/Z/X/blah) is not available."

Comment: Posted an answer for you on SF before I saw this here
http://serverfault.com/questions/198776/redirecting-url-to-different-web-app-in-tomcat/199277#199277

Comment: Thanks for the notion you posted there (basically, putting Context into server.xml).  I will experiment with that, but the downsides make me leery; I'm torn between the server.xml approach and using a proxy servlet (per comments to answer below).

Comment: @user54373: the "standard" approach for production sites is mod_proxy on an Apache. i've given the Tomcat workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen that done with Tomcat.

A common solution is to hide the Tomcat server behind an Apache2 server using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: same solution i was thinking.

Comment: Well, as to that ... I could do this, but I have no non-servlet content; I am concerned that I'll slow down performance by forwarding through Apache server.

Comment: Another thing I've thought of is to make a web application Z which maps a servlet to /Z/X and /Z/Y and uses c=getContext("/X") or "/Y", then rd=c.getRequestDispatcher() from that context and rd.forward().  We'll be forwarding, but "inside" the tomcat container, without an actual HTTP request.

Comment: I doubt getRequestDispatcher can resolve URLs that belong to different webapps... besides, you would need to translate addresses in links.

Comment: I experimented with this, and got good results with gRD against another webapp.  It works if you use getServletContext("/otherwebapp") and set crossContext="true" in the target webapp's context.xml.  Headers and sessions passed through properly too.